# How to receive/get C struct from Python

Tags: python, struct, ctypes

I have a standalone Python module used to perform analysis on some raw data. The module is working great.

Now I need the output generated by the Python module in C source that will do further processing on output.

Here is the rough idea of flow:

1. C source will call the Python module.
2. Python module will fill the results generated into a C structure and
   then somehow pass it to C source.

So what is the best way to get the results from Python module in C source code?

Should I use something like the following to fill the results?

```
from ctypes import *
class result(Structure):       
    _fields_ = [("status", c_int), ...]
```

Comment: Not really the prettiest way, but I think the easiest way will be to have your python module dump output to a temporary file, and then read the file in C.

Comment: I think this should be the last way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you'll want to use the ctypes module — that module is for accessing DLLs and shared objects *from* Python code, not the other way around.

You don't specify how the C program is going to invoke the Python module. Will it

- invoke the Python script using something like `popen` from C? If so, then you can write data to `stdout` in Python and interpret the data appropriately in C. You'll have to design your own little protocol for this. This can be an ad-hoc protocol, or you can use existing formats like JSON, for which you'll find libraries for both C and Python.
- [embed the Python VM in your C program?](http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html) Then you'll need to convert the C values into appropriate `Py*` values and put them into a `PyTuple` that you can pass as an argument to the Python function, from C. The output of the Python function will be a [`PyObject`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/structures.html#PyObject), which you'll have to unpack (in C) to get the data.

In both cases, you'll need to do the packing and unpacking yourself.

Comment: Great Thanks. Currently i am using popen to invoke the python script. As i need a quick solution, so i will read/write data from stdout.